# Mongo Query that always returns zero documents

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

It's possible to write a query that always returns all of the elements in a collection, to use pymongo as an example:

```
MongoClient()["database"]["collection"].find({})
```

However, due to the structure of my code, I would quite like to be able to construct a query that does the opposite, a query that will necessarily return zero elements in all situations:

```
MongoClient()["database"]["collection"].find(null_query)
```

How can I define `null_query`, such that this is correct?

Comment: I'm not sooo deeply familiar with mongo, but would try something along the lines of querying for an invalid `_id`, or even just give a stab at `{ _id: { $exists: false } }` ...(but it might well be that this is somehow detected to be nonsensical internally, and cause some sort of error...)

Comment: Can you explain the rationale for wanting this? At first glance this seems like a solution looking for a problem, although I may be wrong.

Comment: @yivi The rationale was discussed in the chat, and is *roughly*: The query is supposed to be "auto-generated" by an abstract class. So there has to be an actual *query* that achieves the goal of always returning an empty result. (At least that's how I understood it - maybe it can be edited into the question to make it clearer...)

Comment: @yivi Basically, I have an abstract class for which one of the methods is a query to find certain entries that need to be processed. In some children of this abstract class, this is a no-op.

Comment: But returning a Cursor for an empty Collection doesn't seem entirely useful, is it? You could create the empty Collection and Cursor manually and return that (although is discouraged by the documentation)... but I fail to see the point. "Forcing" MongoClient to return that would be rather useless (hence it doensn't exist). And making a query for a known empty set seems wasteful, at best.

Comment: @yivi To give a more general reason, imagine you are wanting to construct a general algebra for mongo queries using `'$and'` and `'$or'`. You would necessarily want an element `t` for which `t & x = x ∀ x` and an element `f` for which `f | x = x ∀ x`. You find that `t = {}` and `f = null_query` with `null_query` defined as above. In this situation, it would be useful, mine is a slightly simpler case, but in my case, it still makes sense for me to provide a query for which the property of `f` holds true.

Comment: And yet, making a query for a known empty set, as the only answer you have so far suggests, seems both very obvious (_**q**: how to get an empty result? **a**: query for non-existing documents!_) and somewhat wasteful. But if it helps you, more power to you. I don't know, maybe MongoClient does optimize for this scenario.

Comment: @yivi Certainly other designs are possible, but I'd be sacrificing simplicity further up my stack in any alternative solution, whereas this hides the complexity of the operation in more specific parts of my codebase. Perhaps it's some tick that I have that other developers don't need to scratch, but it seems reasonable either way to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask for any field to be in an empty list. It seems reasonable to use the `_id` field for this:

```
db.collection.find({_id: {$in: []}})
```

If you want a shorter query you don't need to use the `_id` field
at all:

```
db.collection.find({_:{$in:[]}})
```

## Alternative if MongoDB version >= 3.4:

Arguably one can also ask if the `_id` field does not exists, which has been suggested by @Marco13:

```
db.collection.find({_id: {$exists: false}})
```

However, this assumes that all documents have the `_id` field, which is not necessarily true for MongoDB versions before 3.4 where a collection could be created with `db.createCollection("mycol", {autoIndexID : false})` so all documents were not automatically given an `_id` field.

Comment: This looks great! A little untidy, but I suspect this is the neatest possible representation. I will have a go tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: Shouldn't `$exists: false` have the same effect as `$in: []` here? (It might be a *little* clearer, but that's probably a subjective detail)

Comment: @Marco13 `$exists: false` works and is probably the neater solution, if you post it, I'll accept it, if not I'll accept this one, which also works!

Comment: @Imran @Marco13 , the `$exists: false` solution doesn't work for documents without an `_id` which can be created with `db.createCollection("noautoid", { autoIndexId: false })`.

Comment: @HaskellElephant True, but it seems like `autoIndexId` was removed in 3.4 (see https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19067 ). If you don't see any other reason to not use it, you could either edit it into your answer as another option (mentioning the caveat of `autoIndexId` and the mongo version), or I'll add it as another answer accordingly.

Comment: @marco13 I have edited it into my answer as you suggested.